# How to execute a 32 bit SSIS package in a 64bit package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, 32bit-64bit

I'm working on a Integration Services project in order to build an ETL.

One of my packages contains multiple script tasks to parse Excel content (Microsoft Ace 12 driver). This package need to be executed in a 32 bit mode (I can't execute this package in 64 bit). I can't install 64 bit version of the driver.

Moreover, I wraped it in a higher level 64bit package.
The "Load calls" package should be executed in a 32bit mode.

[image]

So is there a way to run a 32bit execution package task in a 64bit package ?

Thanks !

Comment: If there are no options in the execute package task, then I'm guessing you're going to have to use a execute process task command to run the 32 bit version of DTEXEC.EXE. What kind of parameters are being passed in and out?

Answer (score 2):

possible to change package execution from 64 bit to  32 bit

Projects Menu->Package Properties(Last in menu)->Debugging

Change Run64BitRuntime->false

[image: Menu][image]

Comment: This trick is to run the package and sub-packages in a 32 bit mode but only in debug (SSDT). My problem is about running one of the sub packages in 32 bit but keep others in 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Execute Process Task instead of executing it as a package. This will respect the x32/x64 setting.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141166.aspx

http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.com/2009/10/quick-reference-ssis-in-32-and-64-bits.html